# Dynamically change label and cell size by text length

Tags: xcode, ios6, autolayout

I have a table with a prototype cell. My project uses auto layout.

The cell holds some labels, theit text length can be various. Sometimes it is too length to fit in its default size.

What I'd like to change label/cell size dynamically to enable to show the whole text. If needed, add more rows automatically.

I'd tried label's sizetofit, it simply does not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText;
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    cellText = [detailPeriodsContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth-40, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 35;
}
```